# Switch statement not working properly - Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, console.log

Switch statement code:

```
var data = "manager";

 switch (data) {
  case "manager" :
  function test(){
     console.log('manager');
  }
  test();
  break; 

  case "worker" :
  function test(){
    console.log('worker');
  }
  test();
  break;

  default:
   console.log('default');
} //output showing as 'worker' but expected output  // 'manager'
```

but if  i try this using if conditions,it will worked correctly.

If statement code:

```
var data = "manager";

 if (data == "manager") {
  function test(){
     console.log('manager');
  }
  test();
 } else if(data == "worker"){
   function test(){
    console.log('worker');
  }
  test();
 } else {
      console.log('default');
 } // got correct output as 'manager'
```

What's wrong with switch statement? is switch working as async?

Comment: Why are there function declarations in a switch statement, if all you're doing, is calling that function immediately?

Comment: Just i want to test, so i put like this, but it worked in if statements, how?

Comment: The function declaration is getting overwritten. This happens due to how JavaScript parser works. It first looks through .js file and functions declared are getting parsed. Hence, calling test which is declared twice calls the most recent declaration

Comment: i wrote this initially as an answer, but i think its more appropriate as a comment as its not  a good solution. the if statements have curly brackets that create an inline scope and therefore you can recreate the function. in the switch statements, you don't have those. in case you would have wrapped each switch statement with a curly brackets, you would achieved the same result. the initial issue is revealing bad coding methods, so you should rethink whatever you are doing

Comment: So we can't write and call same functions inside switch, but we are able to do in if statements am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare a function in `switch` statement cases, and don't declare a function with the same name in different places.

Try this:

```js
var data = "manager";

function testWorker() {
  console.log('worker');
}
function testManager() {
  console.log('manager');
}
    
switch (data) {
  case "manager": testManager(); break;
  case "worker": testWorker(); break;
  default: console.log('default');
}
```

`function` declarations get hoisted to the top of their scope. Since the `switch`'s cases don't have their own scope, both `function test(){` declarations get moved to the top, meaning the `manager` one will override the `worker` declaration.

The only reason your `if / else` variant works, is because these blocks have their own scope. The function is only accessible in their respective `if` / `else` block.

Comment: So we can't write and call same functions inside switch, but we are able to do in if statements am i right?

Comment: I think you mean that case doesn't have its own scope rather than switch doesn't have its own scope.

Comment: the function is **not block scoped**. Here the function is not declared but once declared it is accessible outside.

Answer (score 4):

The if statement puts the function inside a block `{}`, limiting scope.

```js
{
  function test() {
    console.log("one");
  }

  test();

}

function test() {
  console.log("two");
}
```

The switch case does not have block delimiters. So the last `test()` function defined gets called.

```js
function test() {
  console.log("one");
}

test();

function test() {
  console.log("two");
}
```

Comment: So we can't write and call same functions inside switch, but we are able to do in if statements am i right?

Comment: That would not be a good practice doing so. You can check out Cerebrus' answer for a way to do this correctly

Comment: Ok thank you, in my case i am building one application, where i need to use two same functions with two different conditions, is it good approach to use if statement for this?

Comment: If there are only 2 cases, then `if` statement would be a good practice.